# SQL request - Get results from 2 dates in different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, request

I would like to make a request that count all results since yesterday on the first column and do the same thing for the 2nd column but for 2 days.

The request below doesn't work because I would like to find a way to associate my Where clause to a specific column.

```
SELECT
Count(*) as '1 day',
Count(*) as '2 days'
       FROM myTable tbl
       WHERE
       DATEADD(day, 1, MyTimeStampToCompare) >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) as '1 day' and 
       DATEADD(day, 1, MyTimeStampToCompare) >= DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE()) as '2 days'
```

I'm working on SQL Server 2012.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of having it in the where clause just modify it to be in `CASE` statement inside `COUNT` function

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEADD(day, 1, MyTimeStampToCompare) >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) THEN 1
                  ELSE NULL
             END) AS '1 Day'
       ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEADD(day, 1, MyTimeStampToCompare) >= DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()) THEN 1
                   ELSE NULL
              END) AS '2 Day'
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE MyTimeStampToCompare >= DATEADD(day, -4, GETDATE())
```

In the where clause I included last 4 days to shrink number of records returned making it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Longtime no use Ms SQL but, seem you need something like this?

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEADD(day, 1, first_date_col)>= GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '1 day',
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEADD(day, 2, secornd_date_col)>= GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as '2 day',
FROM myTable tbl
```

(fixed! @Vladimir: Intended to use the sum from the beginning when wrote 1 else 0, just forget to change the COUNT :)

Comment: In SQL server when using `COUNT` you need `ELSE NULL` because `COUNT 0 ` and `COUNT 1` will produce same results. As Alternative you can use `SUM`. Lastly you are missing `END` for `CASE` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the WHERE clause goes as far back as the farthest-back count you'd like.

You can use SUM as I do here or COUNT as other answers do. The COUNT relies on NULLs not being counted and can trigger a "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate..." warning.

```
DECLARE @DateTable TABLE
(
    MyTimeStampToCompare datetime
);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-7);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-1);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-1);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-1);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-1);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-1);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-5);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-3);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-5);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-2);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-2);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-2);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate());
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-3);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-6);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-8);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-9);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()+1);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate()-1);
INSERT INTO @DateTable (MyTimeStampToCompare) VALUES (getdate());

SELECT
    SUM
    (
        CASE
            WHEN MyTimeStampToCompare >= DATEADD(day, -1, FLOOR(CONVERT(float,getdate()))) THEN
                1
            ELSE
                0
        END
    ) AS EverythingSince1DayAgo,
    SUM
    (
        CASE
            WHEN MyTimeStampToCompare >= DATEADD(day, -2, FLOOR(CONVERT(float,getdate()))) THEN
                1
            ELSE
                0
        END
    ) AS EverythingSince2DaysAgo
FROM        @DateTable
-- you said you want everything from 2 days ago; this makes sure times are stripped off of the current date so it's midnight this morning, and then marches back 2 days
-- SQL Server 2008+ has fancier mechanisms for removing the time from a date, but I don't have convenient access to test.
WHERE       MyTimeStampToCompare >= DATEADD(day, -2, FLOOR(CONVERT(float,getdate())));

/*
Original poster's errant code:
SELECT
Count(*) as '1 day',
Count(*) as '2 days'
       FROM myTable tbl
       WHERE
       DATEADD(day, 1, MyTimeStampToCompare) >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) as '1 day' and 
       DATEADD(day, 1, MyTimeStampToCompare) >= DATEADD(day, -3, GETDATE()) as '2 days'
*/
```